# Effective search in specific intervals

Tags: c++, algorithm, containers

Suppose we have a double value(`x`) and we need to find in which interval from the below it belongs and return corresponding value:

[image]

I want know what is the most effective way to do this.
I need to call this function dosen of times.
May be keep these values in a set and do binary search, or simply check by `if/else` statements?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are your intervals even?

Comment: I've fixed already :)

Comment: Your ellipsis do not allow to understand the general pattern for the returned value.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I've edited, does it make sense?

Comment: Yep, ok now. (Anyway, in the solution I propose, this is just tabulated.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a std::map for this:

```
std::map<double, double> valueMap;
valueMap[1.0e-5] = 1.0;
valueMap[1.0e-4] = 10.0;
valueMap[1.0e-3] = 100.0;
...
// To get a value from your map, use lower_bound:
double result = *valueMap.lower_bound(5.0e-4); //This will return 1.0
double result2 = *valueMap.lower_bound(5.0e-3); //This will return 10.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following: https://ideone.com/47NYjr

```
double f(double x)
{
    const double range[]  = {10E-5, 10E-4, 10E-3, 10E-2, 10E-1, 1., 10.};
    const double values[] = {-1., 1., 10., 42., 21., 5., 1., 10.}; // (range + 1) values

    auto it = std::upper_bound(std::begin(range), std::end(range), x);
    return values[std::distance(std::begin(range), it)];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Jarod42, but don't you think that using map is more effective?

Comment: @Heghine: Depends what you need.  A binary search will be a constant factor faster because it uses a minimum amount of memory and avoids pointer-chasing, but a `std::map` allows fast updates.  Note that you could also binary-search a single array of `std::pair`s, instead of 2 arrays.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, I need faster search, because I should call this function O(1000) times, memory not an issue. I'll keep container as a private member of my class and then will use in this function.

Comment: Array is more cache friendly than map (and your range seems constant so no update). And both have logarithm complexity.

Comment: Given the small table size, sequential and binary searches won't make a big difference, and it is possibly better to use an ad-hoc array implementation instead of `std`.

Comment: std::map lower_bound does use binary search to find values; I just want to make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

**Using the `log10` function:**

```
// Table of return values
const double Output[11]= { 1, 10, ... 1.e5, 1.e-5, 1.e-4, ... 0.1, 1 };

// Find the power of 10 (offset to the array origin)
int P10= (int)log10(x) + 5;

// Clamp
if (P10 < 0) P10= 0; else if (P10 > 10) P10= 10;

// Output
return Output[P10];
```

This will cost you a `log` function evaluation, one or two comparisons and a table lookup. (Avoid using the `pow` function.)

**Alternative:**

For sheer performance (especially without an FP coprocessor), you can avoid the evaluation of the `log` by directly getting the exponent value from the IEEE representation (bits 62-52; non-portable). Then, for a given exponent, the mantissa can correspond to just one or two powers of 10.

Keep an array of the next power of 10, for all relevant powers of 2, and compare to x.

```
double Next10[]= { ... /* 2^-4 */ 0.1, /* 2^-3 */ 1., /* 2^-1 */ 1., /* 2^-0 */ 1., /* 2^1 */ 10., /* 2^2 */ 10., ...  };
double Output[]= { ... 1.e5, 1.e-5, 1.e-5, 1.e-5, 1.e-4, 1.e-4, ...};

// Get the exponent (bit-field or explicit shifts) and offset it (exponent + array origin)
int P2= ((IEEE*)&x)->Exponent + 1024 + 17; // The Next10 table starts at 2^-17 < 10-5

// Clamp the exponent
if (P2 < 0) P2= 0; else if (P2 > 34) P2= 34; // The Next10 table ends at 2^17 > 10^5

// Compare x to the power of 10 and return the desired output value
return x < Next10[P2] ? Output[P2] : Output[P2 + 1];
```

Will cost you a bit-field extraction (2 shifts), clamping (1 or 2 integer compares), 1 FP comparison and 2 array accesses.

Should beat anything.